# Making SimpleCov work when executing gem binary

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am trying to add SimpleCov coverage to my gem that has a binary.

I would like to test its command line interface, so I wish to test the binary execution itself, and not the library it uses.

I am getting no coverage report (0 LOC) by SimpleCov.

As I understand, the issue is most likely due to the fact that in my test (either cucumber features or rspec specs), I am executing the gem's binary with `system` or `popen3`, but I don't know how I can tell SimpleCov to "follow through" (or if I am barking at the right tree...).

I have tried playing with `SimpleCov.command_name`, `SimpleCov.pid = $$`, `SimpleCov.track_files` and almost every other remotely related configuration I found.

I do not wish to use Aruba, although I have tried reviewing their source to look for possible answers.

Related code snippets:

```
# spec_helper.rb
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require :default, :development


# test_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "my bin" do
  it "should be covered" do
    system 'bin/runme'
  end
end
```

I have prepared a [minimal repo](https://github.com/DannyBen/simplecov-debug) as an easy testing ground, if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this? https://blog.yossarian.net/2018/04/01/Code-coverage-with-Simplecov-across-multiple-processes

Basically, in your spec_helper.rb

```
if ENV["COVERAGE"]
  require "simplecov"

  # Only necessary if your tests *might* take longer than the default merge
  # timeout, which is 10 minutes (600s).
  SimpleCov.merge_timeout(1200)

  # Store our original (pre-fork) pid, so that we only call `format!`
  # in our exit handler if we're in the original parent.
  pid = Process.pid
  SimpleCov.at_exit do
    SimpleCov.result.format! if Process.pid == pid
  end

  # Start SimpleCov as usual.
  SimpleCov.start
end
```

Then inside your bin/runme, add:

```
  if ENV["COVERAGE"]
    # Give our new forked process a unique command name, to prevent problems
    # when merging coverage results.
    SimpleCov.command_name SecureRandom.uuid
    SimpleCov.start
  end
```

Child process' test coverage will merge into the parent's process.

If you use SimpleCov's `coverage_dir`, make sure it's in all SimpleCov.start blocks so that results are written to same location.

Comment: Thanks for this. Although in most of my new gems I have moved away from testing the bin (and instead code better so that I don't have to), this is still useful in at least one of my gems. I will try it later and accept the answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

well it's not easy to find a solution to this issue in particular.

not sure this solves your problem but maybe a start?

without the start block which modifies the filters i could not get SimpleCov to watch the bin directory (using the sample github repo you provided).

Used ***command_name*** to give the main processes coverage reports a name and then in the fork used command_name to give the forked processes report a name (SimpleCov merges them for us as long as they have different names).

then used ***load*** to load the bin file instead of using ***system***.

(I couldn't figure out a way to make ***system*** or ***spawn*** add to the coverage reports, maybe if you called it through a script that restarts SimpleCov for you with an alternate command_name)

again, not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but may be a start.  code below:

```
# spec_helper.rb
require 'simplecov'

SimpleCov.command_name "main_report"
SimpleCov.start do
    filters.clear # This will remove the :root_filter and :bundler_filter that come via simplecov's defaults
    add_filter do |src|
        !(src.filename =~ /^#{SimpleCov.root}/) unless src.filename =~ /bin/ #make sure the bin directory is allowed
    end
end

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.require :default, :development



# test_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe "my bin" do
    it "should be covered" do
        pid = Process.fork do
            SimpleCov.start do 
                command_name "bin_report_section"
            end
            load "bin/runme"
        end

    end
end
```

result:

> Coverage report generated for bin_report_section, main_report to
>   /home/korreyd/simplecov-debug/coverage.
>   1 / 1 LOC (100.0%) covered.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like progress, but the thing that might make this solution still problematic, is the "load" call. In the "real life" problem, I need to use popen3, to capture stdout, stderr and exit status conveniently. Like in [this cucumber stepdef](https://github.com/DannyBen/clicumber/blob/master/features/step_definitions/clicumber.rb#L59) - but still, I will try to work with what you have provided here.